# implementing a non-linear relationship within a cox proportional hazards model using the survival package in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am modeling tree mortality based on tree census data. People go out at various intervals, and record whether trees lived or died. I am using the `coxph` function to run a cox proportional hazard model to analyze the probability of tree mortality as a function of several predictor variables. The code looks like:

```
 model <- coxph(S ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data)
```

However, one of my predictors, tree size, is actually expected to have a non-linear relationship with mortality probability. Specifically, trees die a lot when they are small, the probability of death goes down as they reach a 'juvenile' stage and are an intermediate size, and then the mortality probability creeps back up as trees get older and larger in size. This creates a 'inverse J shaped' pattern between mortality probability and tree size. It looks like this:
[image: relationship between tree size and mortality probability]

How can I incorporate this non-linear relationship into the coxph framework? If this is not possible, how else can I analyze the mortality probability in the R environment, using a JAGS model or something else?

Comment: Perhaps try transforming the tree size variable? Maybe try log(treesize) or something of the sort to try and get the relationship closer to linear.

Comment: @cgage if the J could be approximated by a transformation to linear, I would go for it (i.e. if it was a straight exponential relationship). Unfortunately, I don't think such a simple fix can be applied in this case.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi splines won't fit this form necessarily though. I don't think this would do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
library(mgcv)
fit <- gam(S ~ s(x1, bs = 'cr', k = 10) + s(x2, bs= 'cr', k = 10) +
           s(x3, bs = 'cr', k = 10), family = cox.ph(), data = data)
```

You can fit an **additive Cox proportional hazards model**, where all terms are non-linear splines. See `?cox.ph` for extensive examples.

If you have not used `mgcv` before, you may need to look at `?gam` and `?s` as well. After model fitting, `summary.gam()`, `gam.check()` and `predict.gam()` are your friends.